# How to convert time taken by a command into seconds or minutes in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have run several commands and noted time taken by a command?

I got output like this in an excel column

126m52.091

136m14.472s

152m25.196s

65m45.490s

**how can i convert this mixture of minutes and seconds into seconds in excel?**

Results should be like this

7612.091

8174.472

...

Having an excel formula will really help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With data in **A1**, use:

```
=TIMEVALUE("00:" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"s",""),"m",":"))*60*60*24
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

1. the formula discards the **s** if it is present.
2. the formula creates a time-string like:  00:136:14.472
3. converts into a true Excel time *(with TIMEVALUE)*
4. converts the time to seconds